# Attempting to create the holy grail layout using flex-box, and I struggle with my sidebar, not going to the bottom

Tags: html, css, sidebar

As the title says, I am tackling the holy grail layout using flex-box, in an self paced self learning curriculum, and for some reason I dont understand why my sidebar isn't extending all the way down to the footer.
Here is my codepen - https://codepen.io/koicel/pen/RwQwrer?editors=1100

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>The Holy Grail</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="test2">
      <div class="header">MY AWESOME WEBSITE</div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">⭐ - link one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">‍♂️ - link two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">️ - link three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> - link four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="cards">
          <div class="card">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora,
            eveniet? Dolorem dignissimos maiores non delectus possimus dolor
            nulla repudiandae vitae provident quae, obcaecati ipsam unde impedit
            corrupti veritatis minima porro?
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi
            quaerat qui iure ipsam maiores velit tempora, deleniti nesciunt fuga
            suscipit alias vero rem, corporis officia totam saepe excepturi odit
            ea.
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo
            ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure
            nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia
            esse autem?
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum
            sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde
            earum minima laboriosam eos!
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo
            ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure
            nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia
            esse autem?
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum
            sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde
            earum minima laboriosam eos!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">The Odin Project ❤️</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* width: 1500px; */
}

.header {
  height: 72px;
  background: darkmagenta;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.footer {
  height: 72px;
  background: #eee;
  color: darkmagenta;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  background: royalblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 50px;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  border-radius: 4px;
  flex: 1 1 250px;
}

.cards {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  width: 1000px;
  gap: 50px;
  padding: 40px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.test2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To let Flexbox know you wish to expand an element to the maximum available width (for `flex-direction: row` or height (for `flex-direction: column`), you'll need to set the `flex-grow` property.

On both the nav containers (`.test2` and `.container`), set the `flex-grow: 1` property and they will both take all the available space that is set by your `body` element.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.test2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

And that's it, your navigation sidebar is all the way to the footer :)